# QtabBar text and icon

Tags: c++, qt, qtabbar

hi i would like to place icon and an text below the icon in each tab of an tabbar in QtabBar widget. by default the text and icon are set next to each other i would like to display one below the other . how can we do it .

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be only one way to change icon placement - reimplement QTabBar's paintEvent.
Code like this may help:

```
class MyTabBar : public QTabBar
{
    ...
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
        QStylePainter painter(this);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            QStyleOptionTabV2 option;
            initStyleOption(&option, i);
            painter.drawItemPixmap(option.rect, Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignHCenter, option.icon);
            painter.drawItemText(option.rect, Qt::AlignBottom|Qt::AlignHCenter, palette(), 1, option.text);
        }
    }
};
```