# Internal QWidgets of QTabBar's tab?

Tags: c++, qt, qtabbar

As a follow up of " [Hide label text for Qt tabs without setting text to empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851977/hide-label-text-for-qt-tabs-without-setting-text-to-empty-string) " :

Can I directly access the widgets within the tabs of the `QTabBar`. I do **not** mean the corresponding widget which is shown when I select a tab, but the tab's widgets (so in the screenshot below the log label and log icon).

[image: TabBar]

I have tried `QTabBar::findChildren`, but with no success. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try the `QTabBar::tabButton()` and `QTabBar::tabIcon()` functions?

Comment: `tabIcon` gives me a `const QIcon`, which I can not modify - OK I can set an entirely new icon. `tabButton` always returns `nullptr`: Tried `QWidget *w = this->m_tabBar->tabButton(0, QTabBar::RightSide);` with left and right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QTabBar` header sections are not actually widgets. They are drawn by `QStylePainter` inside `QTabBar::paintEvent`. Thus you can't get access to them.
As a workaround you can add a tab with an empty text and set a custom widget to it:

```
QTabBar *bar = new QTabBar;
bar->addTab("");

QLabel *label = new QLabel("my label");
bar->setTabButton(0, QTabBar::LeftSide, label);
```

Comment: Works well, one caveat. Even the empty text of a tab consumes some space however. So I have some unintended space left there.

Comment: I think you should be able to adjust that by using a style sheet, try with min-width and padding properties.