# Floating sub QMainWindow (QMainWindow as child widget of main QMainWindow)

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qmainwindow, qdockwidget

I use a `QMainWindow` as **child** of my main `QMainWindow`. By that I get an other area which I can use for dockable widgets (`QDockWidget`).

According to the following posts this is OK, it also works perfectly for me.

1. https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17519
2. http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/12569-QMainWindow-as-a-child-of-QMainWindow

To make the `QMainWindow` behaving as a normal widget, I unset the window flag, this trick is mentioned in one of the posts above.

Now I also want to be able to float this child `QMainWindow` with all its docked widgets. In other words, I want to revert the step "making it a normal widget". Unfortunately,  this does does not work. It is gone from the main window, but not visible at all.

Any way to resolve it?

```
// this is the child QMainWindow
if (this->m_infoAreaFloating)
{
    // this should give me a floating window besides the main window
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Desktop);
    this->show();
}
else
{
    // make this compliant as QWidget
    this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() & ~Qt::Window);
}
```

Related: [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897261/internal-qwidgets-of-qtabbars-tab) , [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851977/hide-label-text-for-qt-tabs-without-setting-text-to-empty-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Qt::Desktop` flag is not something you are supposed to set by yourself.

You need to set the `Qt::Window` flag:

```
setWindowFlags(m_infoAreaFloating ? Qt::Window : Qt::Widget);
show();
```

There's no point to `this->windowFlags() & ~Qt::Window`: you've cleared all other window flags when setting the lone `Qt::Window` flag. You're in full control of the flags, there's no need to preserve some "other" flags: there are none.