Is it possible to add MainWindow in another widget in QtDesigner5?
In my scenario, I want to show the assembly code and some other states of each threads. I hope that they can own their Dock Widgets which hold the thread states.
Here is an example code generated by ChatGPT
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QTextBrowser, QDockWidget, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit

class ThreadView(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadView, self).__init__(parent)

        # Create the central text browser
        self.textBrowser = QTextBrowser()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textBrowser)

        # Create the left dock widget
        self.dockWidgetLeft = QDockWidget("Source Code", self)
        self.dockWidgetLeft.setAllowedAreas(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea)
        self.sourceCodeEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.dockWidgetLeft.setWidget(self.sourceCodeEdit)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.dockWidgetLeft)

        # Create the right dock widget
        self.dockWidgetRight = QDockWidget("GPR Values", self)
        self.dockWidgetRight.setAllowedAreas(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)
        self.gprValuesEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.dockWidgetRight.setWidget(self.gprValuesEdit)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dockWidgetRight)

        # Set initial text for demonstration
        self.textBrowser.setPlainText("Assembly code")
        self.sourceCodeEdit.setPlainText("Source code")
        self.gprValuesEdit.setPlainText("GPR values")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Thread State Viewer")

        # Create a QTabWidget
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabWidget)

        # Add tabs for each thread
        for i in range(3):  # Example for 3 threads
            thread_view = ThreadView()
            self.tabWidget.addTab(thread_view, f"Thread {i+1}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.resize(800, 600)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

It shows the possibility to add a QMainWindow (class ThreadView here) into another widget (QTabWidget here). However, I can't find any way to create a QMainWindow so I can put it into a tab widget. Is it possible to do that in QtDesigner5?

While not technically impossible, it fundamentally makes no sense to add a QMainWindow to a QTabWidget, and support for their own dock widgets is probably unreliable. Seriously, do not ask such questions to gen AI, they have absolutely no awareness of what they "talk" about. Do proper research about how such models work, and you'll stop using them for such coding purposes, as it's completely pointless.

In my case, I have an instruction stream which yields the cycle and PCs executed at that cycle.  I want to see both assembly and C++ source code at each cycle. I use DockWidget because the source code might be too long to be displayed in a small window. DockWidget let user can drag them out of the mainwindow which can solve this problem. I also need to show the states of multiple threads. TabWidget helps and keep the view clean. Is there another way to achieve my goal?

Designer doesn't allow to add QMainWindows as child widgets. Note that if you need to "undock" a widget in order to see its contents more appropriately, it's probably a UI design issue (or poor implementation).

I found that someone did that before. (https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/12569-QMainWindow-as-a-child-of-QMainWindow)(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917115/floating-sub-qmainwindow-qmainwindow-as-child-widget-of-main-qmainwindow) and no one said that's a bad thing. What's your basis? or your assertion just a prejudice? "Designer doesn't allow to add QMainWindows as child widgets" who said that? If you think that's a bad design, you should at least give an example. Please tell me the reference or the reason or that comments are meaningless.

First of all, that post is more than 15 years old, 2 major versions have been released in the meantime, and while the QMainWindow API hasn't changed that much in that period, some portions of its code have; interestingly enough, many of them deal with docking. While there's nothing technically wrong in adding a child QMainWindow, its own dock management mostly relies on the fact that the main window is assumed to be a top level one; therefore, while it could work, it's not explicitly supported. There's no prejudice here, but years long studying of the C++ sources and further personal »

» experimenting with QMainWindow capabilities and possible expandibility of dock features, possibilities that I can assure you are quite limited since most of its implementation uses private classes or functions; that's why some have decided to implement their own "main window" or custom docking framework. Yes, Designer doesn't allow adding QMainWindows as children for a simple reason: top level widgets (including QDialog) are not intended to be used as children, that's why they are not listed in the "widget box" and therefore there's no »

» immediate way to add them within the Designer UI. The only option would be to use a basic promoted QWidget which would be a bit pointless, since it wouldn't provide any proper customization (including adding its own docks); a dedicated Designer plugin may be written, but I doubt it would allow dock customization, unless you want to write the whole implementation (which is quite difficult to begin with even for extremely basic widgets). I never said that your design is bad, but that it may be: without precisely knowing how you actually implemented your UI and the reasoning behind it, I »

» can only make suppositions, and certainly not examples based on a vague description. So, the answer is still the same: it's not possible to directly add a child QMainWindow to another widget in Designer. Using widget promotion would be pointless for your purpose, as they would just be empty placeholders; creating a plugin would most certainly be not worth it, considering its difficulties. Just do that by code, and hope that implementing its aspects doesn't create any inconsistency in user interaction, because, in my experience, it does (and quite annoyingly).

Thanks for your reply. It gives me more insight on how Qt library works and let me know its problem. I have never known KDAB before that. It seems there are many issues in the original Qt library. It really helps.

They are not real issues, at least not for standard and common usage. The dock widget management may not be completely satisfactory, but since providing a more flexible API would require lots of major changes in the QMainWindow codebase, they probably decided that it's not worth changing it, since it works for generic usage and implementing such dramatic changes would create lots of issues in existing programs that just use the known and established behavior (including its quirks and oddities).
