# Disable secondary scroll button (tear indicator?) in QTabBar

Tags: c++, qdockwidget, qt5.3, qtabbar

I have a `QTabBar` looking like this. The screenshot does **not** show the arrow scroll buttons on its right side. What is the thing on left side called (looking like a torn edge)? It serves as a scroll left button. Is it the tear indicator? I found something like this in the style sheets:

```
QTabBar::tear { image: url(tear_indicator.png); }
```

How can I disable it?

[image: QTabBar]

> ^ here, looking like a torn edge, clickable, works like scroll left

Remark: The [tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897261/internal-qwidgets-of-qtabbars-tab) is the one appearing automatically with `QDockWidget` s, none I have created on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove it by StyleSheet

```
QTabBar::tear {
    width: 0px; 
    border: none;
}
```